# Organizando array de resposta

Tags: php, mysql

Como organizar o índice do array da 2ª dimensão?

Busca

```
  $stmt = getConn()->query("SELECT hash,id,quantidade FROM pergaminhos");
  $resp = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_GROUP|PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);
```

resposta

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 2
            [2] => 3
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 4
        )
)
```

resposta desejada

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [1] => 1
            [2] => 1
            [3] => 1
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [4] => 1
        )
)
```

forma escrita para melhor entendimento

```
Array
(
    [valor_do_hash] => Array
        (
            [valor_do_id] => valor_do_quantidade
            [valor_do_id] => valor_do_quantidade
            [valor_do_id] => valor_do_quantidade
        )

    [valor_do_hash] => Array
        (
            [valor_do_id] => valor_do_quantidade
        )
)
```

Comment: Mas o objetivo é cada chave de cada sub-array aumentar em `1` ? Ou existe algum caso em que isso não seja verdade ? E qual a intenção em fazer isso ? Não seria melhor quando vai utilizar fazer a modificação que pretende à chave antes de modificar ?

Comment: @Isac na verdade, ele já esta obtendo o resultado, tanto que falei pra ele que, como ele já tem o resultado o correto é apagar a minha resposta. Pra mim poder apagar a resposta, ele deve desmarcar ela como correta/aceita.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$stmt = getConn()->query("SELECT hash,id,quantidade FROM pergaminhos");
$resp = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_GROUP|PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);

$novaResp = array();

foreach ($resp as $linha) {
    $novaResp[$linha[0]][$linha[1]] = $linha[2];
}

print_r($novaResp);
```

Comment: uma duvida o fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_GROUP|PDO::FETCH_COLUMN) é php que trabalha ou mysql? pois caso seja o php seria melhor ja trabalhar tudo no foreach, pois não sei se estou certo mais com o group e o column vai ativar 2 motores uma vezs interna na fetch e outra no foreach, ai axo mais leve trabalhar no foreach

Answer (score 2):

Utilize a função [`array_map`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-map.php) para percorrer o array e aplicar um função a cada elemento percorrido:

```
$Resposta = array_map(function($Valor) {
  // Faz alguma coisa com "$Valor"
}, $Resposta);
```

utilize a função [`array_values`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-values.php) para pegar todos os valores do elemento atual "`$Valor`":

```
$Chaves = array_values($Valor);
```

depois, utilize a função [`array_fill_keys`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-fill-keys.php) para criar um array, sendo os valores de `$Chaves` como índices e 1 como valor de cada elemento desse array:

```
return array_fill_keys($Chaves, 1);
```

pronto, o código completo:

```
$Resposta = [
  1 => [
    0 => 1,
    1 => 2,
    2 => 3,
  ],
  2 => [
    0 => 4
  ]
];
$Resposta = array_map(function($Valor) {
  $Chaves = array_values($Valor);
  return array_fill_keys($Chaves, 1);
}, $Resposta);
```

se der um `print_r` terá a saída:

```
Array
(
  [1] => Array
  (
    [1] => 1
    [2] => 1
    [3] => 1
  )

  [2] => Array
  (
    [4] => 1
  )
)
```

[Veja funcionando em repl.it](https://repl.it/repls/NiftyBigAbility)

#### Referências

- [`array_map`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-map.php)
- [`array_values`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-values.php)
- [`array_fill_keys`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-fill-keys.php)

Comment: mas ai não compensa fazer um loop e organizar n? ai so esta escondendo o loop... o loop no myql não é mais leve n?

Comment: na verdade axo que vou fazer assim olha, axo que utilizo menos os motores de loop, ja que la no fetchall ja estou usando motores de loop interno do php, e nao do mysql queria algo que descarregasse os loop do php ja que do mysql dizem que é melhor

Comment: $stmtz22 = getConn()->query("SELECT hash,id,quantidade FROM pergaminhos");
  $wwwwz = $stmtz22->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

  $org_receita_padrao = [];
  foreach($wwwwz as $data){
  $org_receita_padrao[$data->hash][$data->id] = $data->quantidade;
  }
  print_r($org_receita_padrao);

Comment: to tentando passa essas função para o mysql

Comment: não deu pra remover